# How to generate Java files from WSDL when 'lang' already defined?

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, xjc, wsimport

I'm trying to turn a WSDL file into Java code using `wsimport` by running this command (which should work from anyone's machine):

```
wsimport https://webservices-uatprod.dhisco.com/OTAHotelDescriptiveInfo/web_services?WSDL -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -B-XautoNameResolution -Xnocompile
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR] 'lang' is already defined
  line 93 of http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 43 of http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd

[ERROR] 'space' is already defined
  line 102 of http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 89 of http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd

[ERROR] 'base' is already defined
  line 109 of http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 113 of http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd

[ERROR] 'specialAttrs' is already defined
  line 117 of http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 157 of http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd
```

I've spent hours googling this to try and find the solution.  I'm relatively convinced I need to specify a binding file with the `-b binding.xml` flag.

However, I'm having a very hard time figuring out how to create that binding file.  Here's what I've attempted:

**binding.xml**

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd"
              jaxb:version="2.0">
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='lang']">
        <jaxb:property name="langAttribute"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Then with this in place, I try running with the binding file by:

```
wsimport https://webservices-uatprod.dhisco.com/OTAHotelDescriptiveInfo/web_services?WSDL -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -B-XautoNameResolution -Xnocompile -b binding.xml
```

And now I get:

```
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//xs:attribute[@name='lang']" results in empty target node
  line 6 of file:/Users/name/git/foo/bar/src/main/resources/wsdl/binding.xml
```

I've tried many other combinations of the binding file's XPath... I figure I need to rename the attribute of all elements from 'lang' to something else, but I really have been having a hard time figuring it out.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Solution Update**:
I got past this error by downloading the schemas locally, and wherever there was a reference to `schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd"` and `schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"`, I edited the XML to point to my local copy of the file on the file system.

I.e. opened up each *.xsd file where there was reference to these files, and updated each line from something like this:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>
```

To this:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="./xml.xsd"/>
```

After that, it was able to generate the Java classes using the `wsimport` syntax above (did require one small binding file, but that was related to an vendor-defined class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've bound your `xs` prefix to the XML namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd`, but it should be bound to the XML Schema namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Another problem you'll face is that your schema seem to address `xml.xsd` via two different locations: `http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd` and `http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd`. That will get you a lot fo duplicates. You can try to resolve them via catalogs like:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/2001/03/" "http://www.w3.org/2001/"
```

(And the use it with `-catalog`.)

But I'm not sure this will work. In a similar situation I've created a full local copy of schemas I needed to compile and patched them to use uniform schema locations.

> I tried downloading the schemas and xml files locally, but am not sure how to tell wsimport to look for the local copies instead of going out to the internet. If I have a copy of xsd.xml locally... is there a way to tell wsimport to use that instead of any it may find on the internet?

I'm not exactly sure about `wsimport` but generally it is done with catalogs. Assume you've downloaded schemas from `http://www.w3.org` in the directory `w3c`. Then you'll have a catalog file like

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/" "w3c/"
```

Then you should be able to use this catalog file via `wsimport -catalog mycatalog.cat ...`. `wsimport` or underlying schema compiler `xjc` should get your `http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd` schema from `w3c/2001/xml.xsd` then.

However, I've never tried it with `wsimport`, I just routinely use it with `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

Comment: I tried downloading the schemas and xml files locally, but am not sure how to tell wsimport to look for the local copies instead of going out to the internet.  If I have a copy of `xsd.xml` locally... is there a way to tell wsimport to use that instead of any it may find on the internet?

Comment: You do it with catalog files. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `maven-jaxb2` plugin and `wsimport` are both invoking `xjc` to get a lot of this work done.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I was able to get it to compile by downloading the schemas all locally, and updating the schemas to point to one local copy of  "http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd" "http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd".  'Course now I'm on to the next error which I'm pretty sure is vendor-specific but at least this issue is solved.  Thanks again.